# Form Data - Get Values of Fields - DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the REST API and I would like to know how I can access the fields / values of a completed envelope. I can already get the status etc, but I want the fields actually on the screen where the user can change.

I am struggling to see anything in the document to show this.

Also, is there a way to be able to have the Form Data (which you can get in the GUI) using the REST API?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Sure, you want to use the include_tabs parameter on the URL: GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?include_tabs=true.   Link to the documentation: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Recipient%20Status.htm?Highlight=include_Tab

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from REST via the All Recipients as mentioned above in the comment from Luis:

```
https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId‌​}/recipients?include_tabs=true.
```

OR Specificly per recipient like:

```
https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId‌​}/recipients/{reciepientId‌​}/tabs
```

Sample Result for ALL below and for specified Recipient below that (note signers node for "all recipients" is excluded for Recipient tabs Resource:

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 1",
            "value": "",
            "width": 288,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t1[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "142",
            "tabId": "7881cacc-8c7f-4009-a1bb-b418360b7baf"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 2",
            "value": "",
            "width": 306,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 11,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t2[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "300",
            "yPosition": "142",
            "tabId": "3444f6d3-60d7-4206-86fe-7516e96096f8"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 3",
            "value": "",
            "width": 288,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t3[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "178",
            "tabId": "a30c2151-2f28-4d41-a6c9-55ea6837c847"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 4",
            "value": "",
            "width": 306,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 11,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t4[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "300",
            "yPosition": "178",
            "tabId": "12c22e40-36d1-479d-b6a1-960f906ae702"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 5",
            "value": "",
            "width": 600,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t7[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "201",
            "tabId": "cc75998a-7c8a-4bb2-9bcd-449c1c32cca8"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 6",
            "value": "",
            "width": 600,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t8[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "225",
            "tabId": "45e05ada-ca89-4635-900d-9afe0534ae28"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 7",
            "value": "",
            "width": 600,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t9[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "259",
            "tabId": "1f5e614f-aa8d-4dc0-b356-a55412f4dad7"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 8",
            "value": "",
            "width": 114,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t10[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "149",
            "yPosition": "334",
            "tabId": "494b549e-c920-4b65-bac1-b8a9267ca195"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 14",
            "value": "",
            "width": 96,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t11[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "206",
            "yPosition": "562",
            "tabId": "8e71e139-ded2-48dd-99ad-dae637857f26"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 15",
            "value": "",
            "width": 96,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t14[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "300",
            "yPosition": "562",
            "tabId": "76d6cc11-4886-4d4d-9d75-b7436216bc92"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 16",
            "value": "",
            "width": 96,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t17[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "394",
            "yPosition": "562",
            "tabId": "227e770d-5466-4a68-a4e7-b102d18d1f2f"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 17",
            "value": "",
            "width": 96,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t20[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "487",
            "yPosition": "562",
            "tabId": "a298746e-10c6-4c56-972c-c2b1b516cbcd"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 19",
            "value": "",
            "width": 138,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t38[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "437",
            "yPosition": "682",
            "tabId": "73ff7440-3ffe-4dcb-b0ef-c6cefa9bf653"
          },
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text 20",
            "value": "",
            "width": 540,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t50[0]",
            "fontSize": "size8",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "84",
            "yPosition": "706",
            "tabId": "7dabf89f-cda2-4179-8498-91da3f1eb6b7"
          }
        ],
        "checkboxTabs": [
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 9",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb1[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "369",
            "tabId": "00f4a112-4dd6-4028-b07f-9accf8037a22"
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 10",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb2[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "405",
            "tabId": "cbaad3f7-98c4-4f8e-9ce1-fe5b94c588a8"
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 11",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb3[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "429",
            "tabId": "6e262874-04ca-4122-a82e-ca98bd757cb4"
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 12",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb4[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "453",
            "tabId": "5df3f2ae-43ed-43e6-8709-f887b2e38abd"
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 13",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb5[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "501",
            "tabId": "f351e5ea-7a16-4a87-b3c0-78066d207e7f"
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkbox 18",
            "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb7[0]",
            "selected": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "558",
            "yPosition": "585",
            "tabId": "543d5dd3-37b2-4fa9-abdf-a3543dc522fd"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "David W Grigsby",
      "email": "david.grigsby@docusign.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "recipientIdGuid": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "requireIdLookup": "false",
      "userId": "c28af464-771d-4d47-af98-1d2bc2d1d48f",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "status": "sent"
    }
  ],
  "agents": [],
  "editors": [],
  "intermediaries": [],
  "carbonCopies": [],
  "certifiedDeliveries": [],
  "inPersonSigners": [],
  "recipientCount": "1",
  "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

Sample like Result like for recipient:

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 1",
      "value": "",
      "width": 288,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t1[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "34",
      "yPosition": "142",
      "tabId": "7881cacc-8c7f-4009-a1bb-b418360b7baf"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 2",
      "value": "",
      "width": 306,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 11,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t2[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "300",
      "yPosition": "142",
      "tabId": "3444f6d3-60d7-4206-86fe-7516e96096f8"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 3",
      "value": "",
      "width": 288,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t3[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "34",
      "yPosition": "178",
      "tabId": "a30c2151-2f28-4d41-a6c9-55ea6837c847"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 4",
      "value": "",
      "width": 306,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 11,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t4[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "300",
      "yPosition": "178",
      "tabId": "12c22e40-36d1-479d-b6a1-960f906ae702"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 5",
      "value": "",
      "width": 600,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t7[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "34",
      "yPosition": "201",
      "tabId": "cc75998a-7c8a-4bb2-9bcd-449c1c32cca8"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 6",
      "value": "",
      "width": 600,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t8[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "34",
      "yPosition": "225",
      "tabId": "45e05ada-ca89-4635-900d-9afe0534ae28"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 7",
      "value": "",
      "width": 600,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t9[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "34",
      "yPosition": "259",
      "tabId": "1f5e614f-aa8d-4dc0-b356-a55412f4dad7"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 8",
      "value": "",
      "width": 114,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t10[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "149",
      "yPosition": "334",
      "tabId": "494b549e-c920-4b65-bac1-b8a9267ca195"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 14",
      "value": "",
      "width": 96,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 10,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t11[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "206",
      "yPosition": "562",
      "tabId": "8e71e139-ded2-48dd-99ad-dae637857f26"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 15",
      "value": "",
      "width": 96,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 10,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t14[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "300",
      "yPosition": "562",
      "tabId": "76d6cc11-4886-4d4d-9d75-b7436216bc92"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 16",
      "value": "",
      "width": 96,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 10,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t17[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "394",
      "yPosition": "562",
      "tabId": "227e770d-5466-4a68-a4e7-b102d18d1f2f"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 17",
      "value": "",
      "width": 96,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "true",
      "maxLength": 10,
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t20[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "487",
      "yPosition": "562",
      "tabId": "a298746e-10c6-4c56-972c-c2b1b516cbcd"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 19",
      "value": "",
      "width": 138,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t38[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "437",
      "yPosition": "682",
      "tabId": "73ff7440-3ffe-4dcb-b0ef-c6cefa9bf653"
    },
    {
      "height": 11,
      "name": "Text 20",
      "value": "",
      "width": 540,
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-t50[0]",
      "fontSize": "size8",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "84",
      "yPosition": "706",
      "tabId": "7dabf89f-cda2-4179-8498-91da3f1eb6b7"
    }
  ],
  "checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 9",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb1[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "369",
      "tabId": "00f4a112-4dd6-4028-b07f-9accf8037a22"
    },
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 10",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb2[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "405",
      "tabId": "cbaad3f7-98c4-4f8e-9ce1-fe5b94c588a8"
    },
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 11",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb3[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "429",
      "tabId": "6e262874-04ca-4122-a82e-ca98bd757cb4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 12",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb4[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "453",
      "tabId": "5df3f2ae-43ed-43e6-8709-f887b2e38abd"
    },
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 13",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb5[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "501",
      "tabId": "f351e5ea-7a16-4a87-b3c0-78066d207e7f"
    },
    {
      "name": "Checkbox 18",
      "tabLabel": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].p1-cb7[0]",
      "selected": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "locked": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "7cc951a6-4e55-4a9b-a8c4-876932bb91cc",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "558",
      "yPosition": "585",
      "tabId": "543d5dd3-37b2-4fa9-abdf-a3543dc522fd"
    }
  ]
}
```